# Probability of drawing a straight

Tags: probability

What is the probability, if I'm drawing five random cards from a deck, that I will draw 1 ace, 1 two, 1 three, 1 four, and 1 five?
What is the probability that I will draw any type of straight?

(both questions don't care about suit)

thanks!

Comment: Also define straight.

Answer (score 4):

There are $52\choose 5$ hands and $4^5$ Ace-to-five straights. If you include all ten kinds of straight (the higest being ten-to-ace), the number of possible straight hands is $10\cdot 4^5$. If you allow round-the-corner straights, the count is $13\cdot4^5$. The probability is the quotient of "good" by "all" outcomes, of course.

Comment: this is super late, I guess, but do we begin and end with Ace when selecting five straights? As in, do we select consecutive five cards from cards ordered A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K (A)?